# string.format conflcits with css tags : { } 's

Tags: python, html, python-2.7

This is the way i replace variables in my html templates

```
a1 = '<html><title>{0}</title><body>{1}</body></html>'
 vars = ['test', 'test']
 output = a1.format(*vars)
```

the problem is.. this conflicts with css tags when there is css in the html.

because css contains:

```
 {}'s
```

Comment: You should use a proper templating engine.

Comment: Beware of XSS holes.

Comment: i dont have time for template engines.

Comment: And you do have time to solve problems like this one? You should use tools which are specifically designed to do what you want.

Comment: i read my html from a file.. this is for example only.. in the question. i do not have too much html mixed with python

Comment: You could use double braces like `{{ }}`

Comment: not certain why everyone is recommending a template engine. just trying to replace a string in another string that happens to be html mixed with text

Comment: @user4028590: Yes.  And that is exactly what a template engine will help you do easily.

Comment: it is beginning to feel like php and smarty template engine with this { and double {'s..  is there a super fast way to replace things inside of a html / text in python ?

Comment: the concept of "template engine" is probably "another universe".. i already simply read a file and store it in memcache via python.. i just need to replace variables.. my options exist such as using re with regex and python style string.replace() i was simply looking for a faster alternative. i came across string.format but now.. it conflicts with css. if i use double braces.. it will end up feeling like php + smarty years..

Comment: 100% agree with @SLaks, knew about double curlies, but I simply cannot overcome the principles I'm trying to follow :)

Comment: perhaps there is a way to alter python's "string.format" function to use another special character instead of curly braces ?

Answer (score 4):

Alternative approach.

Since you have a mix of HTML and Python code, I would suggest to [separate the logic part and the presentation part](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) by switching to a normal **template engine**.

Example using [`mako`](http://docs.makotemplates.org/en/latest).

Create a template HTML file leaving appropriate "placeholders":

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>${title}</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>${text}</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Then, in the python code, render the template providing the values for placehodlers:

```
from mako.template import Template

t = Template(filename='index.html')
print t.render(title='My Title', text='My Text')
```

This would print:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>My Text</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use double braces to escape them.

like,

```
a1 = """div.test{{ 
 bla;
}}"""
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several good answers to this question, but they may not be appropriate in every circumstance.

- Use a Template Engine: this is a great way to solve the OP's problem, but it may not always possible to install and import a non-standard library like `mako` in every environment.
- Escaping braces `{` with double braces `{{`: this may be honored in some browsers but not others (it probably *should* be honored, but may not be).

Another option when generating html on the fly or bringing it in from a file is to simply manage the order of how the html output is constructed--perform the CSS injection *after* the format operation.

#### Prepare Templates with a Placeholder for the CSS

```py
my_html = """<html>
<head>
    <title>My Page</title>
    <style></style>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Content = {0}</p>
</body>
</html>"""

my_css = """<style>
      body {
        background-color: gray;
      }
    </style>"""
```

#### Prepare the HTML Output with Format

```py
my_page = my_html.format('foobar')
```

#### Inject the CSS After the Format Operation

```py
my_final_page = my_page.replace('<style></style>', my_css)
```

#### Output

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Page</title>
    <style>
      body {
        background-color: gray;
      }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Content = foobar</p>
</body>
</html>
```

You don't have to use the `<style></style>` tag pair as the placeholder. The placeholder could be just about anything as long as it's unique (so you don't inadvertently replace something else, too).

#### Full Example

```py
#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

my_html = """<html>
<head>
    <title>My Page</title>
    <style></style>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Content = {0}</p>
</body>
</html>"""

my_css = """<style>
      body {
        background-color: gray;
      }
    </style>"""

my_page = my_html.format('foobar')

my_final_page = my_page.replace('<style></style>', my_css)

print(my_final_page)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use templates as said by Alecxe or use the formatting with a dictionnary

```
a1 = '<html><title>%(title)s</title><body>%(body)s</body></html>'
vars = {'title': 'test', 'body': 'test'}
output = a1 % vars
```